# How to get/obtain Variables from URL in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, url, split, externalinterface

So I have a URL that I need my Flash movie to extract variables from:

example link:
http://www.example.com/example_xml.php?aID=1234&bID=5678

I need to get the aID and the bID numbers.

I'm able to get the full URL into a String via ExternalInterface

```
var url:String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
if (url) testField.text = url;
```

Just unsure as how to manipulate the String to just get the 1234 and 5678 numbers.

Appreciate any tips, links or help with this!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a new instance of `URLVariables`.

```
// given search: aID=1234&bID=5678
var search:String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.search");
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(search);
trace(vars.aID); // 1234
trace(vars.bID); // 5678
```

Comment: woot thanks :) where can I find info on all the possible "window.location. syntax and what they do

Comment: @Leon, I personally like the Firefox/Gecko reference, but there are other references available.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window#Properties

Answer (score 1):

```
var valuePairs:Array = url.substring(url.indexOf("?")+1).split("&");
var map:Object = new Object();
for (var i:int=0; i < valuePairs.length; i++) {
    var nextValuePair:Array = valuePairs[i].split("=");
    map[nextValuePair[0]] = nextValuePair[1];
}


trace(map["aID"]); // 1234
```

Untested code! This is just with simple string manipulation.

and... almost 1-liner (also untested)

```
var map:Object = new Object();
var temp:Array;
for each (var i:String in /.*\?(.*)/.exec(url)[1].split("&")) map[(temp=i.split("="))[0]]=temp[1];
```

but of course it's probably better to go with urlVariables :)