# as3 get vars from url

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

I found this post and I used the code almost exactly to how they suggested. It doesn't work. Do I need to add something in the php? What am I doing wrong?
Am I missing an import?

Thanks

Here is my code:

**my php link is: www.mySite.com/example.php?id=true**

```
var search:String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.search");
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(search);

if(vars.id)
{
    /// Do something
}
```

Found answer here but doesn't work for me.
[How to get/obtain Variables from URL in Flash AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725231/how-to-get-obtain-variables-from-url-in-flash-as3)

Comment: Are you embedding the .swf file using SWFObject? If yes, did you set `allowscriptaccess:"always"`? http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/control-access-scripts-host-web.html

Comment: I did embed it. I changed it to always and it still is not reading the url. Using firefox. Not sure if this matters.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to get rid of the page address:

```
var search:String = "www.mySite.com/example.php?id=true";
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(search.substr(search.indexOf("?")+1));

if(vars.id) trace(vars.id);
```

Provided that you are sure that the address contains *?* and actual variables you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I needed this so it can read the vars in the url and not have them hard coded in the flash.... var search:String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.search"); But I can't get it to read the url. This is my main issue.